# Check what will be committed before actually committing

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm in the process of learning Mercurial, and even though I installed TortoiseHG, I find myself turning more and more to the command line.

So often I would like to check what the result of a given `hg` command would be before I actually run it. Is there any equivalent to the `-whatif` switch known from PowerShell I can use, or how would you go about checking what would be committed using a given `hg commit` statement?

Comment: what exactly do you want to know? you can check the status of files with `hg status`; `hg help` is your friend

Comment: @Hauge: I use "hg sta" (shorthand for "hg status") all the time to see the file status, along with "hg diff ..." to see what particular change I made to modified files.

Comment: My problem is that I am at the moment not exactly sure how the file selection process works when committing, i.e. if I do a commit with a wildcard file selection argument, will it commit only from the current directory down, or will it commit in the entire directory-structure in the reposistory.

Hence I would like to have some kind of "This command would commit these files" function.

Comment: hg commands always work on the entire repository (apart from per file stuff) in general you can't operate on just some sub directory (unless its a subrepo)

Comment: Really - so theres no chance of using a command like hg commit -m "My commit"  /mydir/*? I'll have to have more repositories then.

Comment: well you can but in DVCSs you usually have more repositories rather than 'the one repository to rule them all' maybe try http://hginit.com/

Comment: @Hauge: you can definitely specify files in a subdirectory to commit: `hg commit mydir`.

Comment: @Hauge: The thing to remember is that it's your shell that expands wildcards, not `hg`. So when you type `hg ci *.c` the wildcard is expanded first and `hg` will see `ci a.c b.c d.c` if those are the files in the local directory. The result is that it works from the local directory down, because that's how the shell works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do commit your message editor will contain a list of files that will be committed in the ignored section. If you commit with `hg -m "message"` this won't work as the editor step is skipped:

```
HG: Enter commit message.  Lines beginning with 'HG:' are removed.
HG: Leave message empty to abort commit.
HG: --
HG: user: User <user@user.land>
HG: branch 'default'
HG: changed myfile.yxy
```

You can use `hg commit` and `hg rollback` to undo the last commit if it contained a file that you did not want to commit. The [rollback](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Rollback) works as long as you did not `hg push` to another repository.

Status works with the same patterns as commit. You can use `hg status some/path/*` and then `hg commit some/path/*` only replacing the command to use.

Answer (score 2):

Often the `-n` switch or `--dry-run` switch will show you what would have happened for a particular command. `commit` doesn't have an `-n` switch, but you could run `hg diff` to see the actual changes, or `hg status` to see what's going on with each file.

Comment: It seems to me that -n is only available for operations impacting remote repositories (e.g., push/pull). And so, there is no dry-run for "hg commit" because "hg rollback" allows to cancel it. Also there is no dry-run for "hg update" because you can always come back to an earlier version. So yes, I guess "hg status" and "hg diff" is the way to go to know what would be committed.

Comment: use `hg status` to get an overview and look at specific files with `hg diff <filename>`; a plain `hg diff` might be hard to read if a lot of files have changed

Comment: Only... rollback is by now deprecated (and I can't find info on how they handle this, only references to "we do deprecation differently")